# JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am starting with React and Typescript and my code editor is claiming about my Button component (error bellow), but to `eslint` seems to be fine.

```js
import React from 'react'

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactChild | React.ReactChildren
}

const Button: React.FunctionComponent = ({ children }: Props) => {
  return <button>{children}</button>
}

export default Button
```

The error:

```js
Type '({ children }: Props) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
  Types of parameters '__0' and 'props' are incompatible.
    Type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' is not assignable to type 'Props'.
      Types of property 'children' are incompatible.
        Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'string | number | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | ReactChildren'.
          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) =>
```

What is wrong on my code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the problem, shoud be:

```js
const Button: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ children }: Props) => (
  <button>{children}</button>
)
```

I was forgetting the `Props` on `React.FunctionComponent`

Comment: Your solution works for me as well. Thanks! Can you please help understand the reason why appending <Props> works in resolving this type error?

Comment: @program_bumble_bee because FunctionComponent requires a type with props